# Why don't references to x inside my for-loop work as intended?

Tags: arrays, r

I'm having trouble running this formula further down in the code, x. In short, I am trying to run this though the forloop to simulate this happening 1000 times.The, hopefully adding up the amount of time TF is true and TS is true. I am getting the error that I'm missing a TRUE/FALSE statement, and tried reworking the function and am still quite stuck. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
#Parameters

c=0.10  #colonization rate

A=10  #Area of all islands(km^2)

d=100 #Distance from host to target (A-T)

s=0.5 #magnitude of distance

d0=100  #Specific "half distance" for dispersal(km)

C1 = c*A*exp(-d/d0)  #Mainland to Target colonization

TS=1    #Target Success

TF=0    #Target Failure

Z =runif(1,0,1)

x <- C1*A

for(i in 1:1000)  

  if(x[i] <= Z) 

    print("TS") 

  if(x[i] >= Z)

    print("TF")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `x` is just 1 scalar value but you're indexing it as if it has 1,000 elements.

```
x
```

> [1] 3.678794

Based on your description it sounds like you just wanted to run your code 1,000 times. This does that:

```
for(i in 1:1000)  {

c=0.10  #colonization rate

A=10  #Area of all islands(km^2)

d=100 #Distance from host to target (A-T)

s=0.5 #magnitude of distance

d0=100  #Specific "half distance" for dispersal(km)

C1 = c*A*exp(-d/d0)  #Mainland to Target colonization

TS=1    #Target Success

TF=0    #Target Failure

Z =runif(1,0,1)

x <- C1*A

if(x <= Z) {
    print("TS") 
  }
if(x >= Z){
  print("TF")
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes that exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks a million Hack-R

Answer (score 1):

With the way you've written code 'x' is not an array but a value, so you can't dereference it the way you've done right now.